# If $a+b+c=x+y+z=ax+by+cz=0$, then find value of $\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}+\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

Tags: contest-math, systems-of-equations, mixing-variables

If $a+b+c=x+y+z=ax+by+cz=0$, then find value of $\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}+\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

From the $a+b+c=0$ equality I tried taking systems of equations into consideration:
$$\begin{cases}
c=-(a+b)\\
z=-(x+y)\\
ax+by+(a+b)(x+y)=0
\end{cases}
$$
which can be later on turned to :
$$\begin{cases}
c=-(a+b)\\
z=-(x+y)\\
(2a+b)x+(a+2b)y=0
\end{cases}
$$
However this is did not put me anywhere near the solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For *whole numbers* the solution is $x = y = z = a = b = c = 0$. Kinda like Euler's $e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$. Nice!

Comment: @AgentSmith How is the first one a solution? $1+1+1$ is $3$ not $0$

Comment: @NobleMushtak, error on my part, didn't see the $0$ at the end

Comment: $(a + b + c)(x + y + z) = ax + by + cz + \text{Lena}$ i.e $(a + b + c)^2 = ax + by + cz + \text{Lena} = (x + y + z)^2$

Comment: Also dot-product of $3$-tuples??!!

Comment: $\begin {bmatrix}a & b & c \end {bmatrix} \times \begin {bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end {bmatrix}$ Can we use *matrices* to solve this *SYSTEM*?

Comment: @AgentSmith See my answer, I didn't use matrices, but I did use vectors and the fact that $ax+by+cz$ represents the dot-product of two 3D vectors.

Answer (score 4):

(i) If $a + 2b \ne 0$, then
$$y = - \frac{(2a + b)x}{a + 2b}.$$

We have
$$x^2 + xy + y^2 = x^2 - x \cdot \frac{(2a + b)x}{a + 2b} + \left(\frac{(2a + b)x}{a + 2b}\right)^2
= \frac{3x^2(a^2 + ab + b^2)}{(a + 2b)^2}.$$

We have
\begin{align*}
 \frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}+\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}
 &= \frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2+(a + b)^2}+\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+(x + y)^2}\\
 &= \frac{a^2}{2a^2 + 2ab + 2b^2}
 + \frac{x^2}{2x^2 + 2xy + 2y^2}\\
 &= \frac{a^2}{2a^2 + 2ab + 2b^2}
 + \frac{x^2}{\frac{6x^2(a^2 + ab + b^2)}{(a + 2b)^2}}\\
 &= \frac{a^2}{2a^2 + 2ab + 2b^2} + \frac{(a+2b)^2}{6(a^2 + ab + b^2)}\\
 &= \frac23.
\end{align*}

(ii) If $a + 2b = 0$, then $a = -2b$
and $-3bx = 0$. Thus, $x = 0$ (*Note*. If $b = 0$, then $a = b = c = 0$). Thus,
$$\frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}+\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}
= \frac23.$$

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to rename the variables, because I think it will make my explanation less confusing: If $x_1+y_1+z_1=x_2+y_2+z_2=x_1x_2+y_1y_2+z_1z_2=0$, then find the value of:
$$
\frac{x_1^2}{x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2}+\frac{x_2^2}{x_2^2+y_2^2+c_2^2}
$$

Let's define some vectors: Let $\vec{v}_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $\vec{v}_2=(x_2,y_2,c_1)$. Clearly, both $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$ are on the plane $x+y+z=0$ since $x_1+y_1+z_1=x_2+y_2+z_2=0$. Moreover, $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$ are perpendicular to each other, i.e. $\vec{v}_1\cdot \vec{v}_2=0$ (where $\cdot$ represents the dot product) because $x_1x_2+y_1y_2+z_1z_2=0$.

Now, without loss of generality, we can assume $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$ are unit vectors. We can assume this without losing generality is because, if $\vec{v}_1$ or $\vec{v}_2$ is not a unit vector, then we can just normalize that vector and all the conditions we need will still hold: Normalizing a vector just changes the length of that vector, so normalization will not change whether the vector is on the plane $x+y+z=0$ and will not change whether the vector is perpendicular to the other vector.

Because we assume $\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2$ are unit vectors, we have
$$
x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2=x_2^2+y_2^2+z_2^2=1
$$
Therefore, the value we want to find becomes just $x_1^2+x_2^2$.

Next, notice that both $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$ are perpendicular to the vector $(1,1,1)$, because $x_1+y_1+z_1=x_2+y_2+z_2=0$. Then, if we normalize $(1,1,1)$, we find that both $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$ are perpendicular to $(1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3})$.

Thus, $\vec{v}_2$ is a unit vector which is perpendicular to both $\vec{v}_1$ and $(1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3})$. It is a common fact that, for any unit vector $\vec{a}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ which is perpendicular to two other unit vectors $\vec{b},\vec{c}\in\mathbb{R}^3$, either $\vec{a}=\vec{b}\times\vec{c}$ or $\vec{a}=-(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})$, where $\times$ here represents the 3D cross-product. Thus, one of the below equations must be true:
$$\vec{v}_2=\vec{v}_1\times (1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3})\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{ or }\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \vec{v}_2=-(\vec{v}_1\times (1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3}))$$
By taking the cross product of $\vec{v}_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ with $(1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3})$, we see that in the first case, the $x$-component of $\vec{v}_2$, which is $x_2$, is $y_1/\sqrt{3}-z_1/\sqrt{3}$. In the second case, the $x$-component of $\vec{v}_2$ is just the negative of this expression, i.e. $x_2=-(y_1/\sqrt{3}-z_1/\sqrt{3})$. However, in either case, when we square this expression, we find that:
$$
x_2^2=\left(\frac{y_1}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{z_1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2=\frac{y_1^2}{3}+\frac{z_1^2}{3}-\frac{2y_1z_1}{3}
$$
Ergo, we have
$$
x_1^2+x_2^2=x_1^2+\frac{y_1^2}{3}+\frac{z_1^2}{3}-\frac{2y_1z_1}{3}
$$
Now, I'm going to split $x_1^2$ into $2x_1^2/3+x_1^2/3$, $y_1^2/3$ into $2y_1^2/3-y_1^2/3$, and $z_1^2/3$ into $2z_1^2/3-z_1^2/3$. By rearranging terms a little, the expression then becomes:
$$
x_1^2+x_2^2=\frac{2}{3}x_1^2+\frac{2}{3}y_1^2+\frac{2}{3}z_1^2+\frac{1}{3}x_1^2-\frac{1}{3}y_1^2-\frac{1}{3}z_1^2-\frac{2}{3}y_1z_1
$$
Factor out $2/3$ from the first three terms and the $-$ sign from the last three terms:
$$
x_1^2+x_2^2=\frac{2}{3}(x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2)+\frac{1}{3}x_1^2-\left(\frac{1}{3}y_1^2+\frac{1}{3}z_1^2+\frac{2}{3}y_1z_1\right)
$$
We know $x_1^2+y_1^2+z_1^2=1$:
$$
x_1^2+x_2^2=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}x_1^2-\left(\frac{1}{3}y_1^2+\frac{1}{3}z_1^2+\frac{2}{3}y_1z_1\right)
$$
Clearly, $(1/3)x_1^2=(x_1/\sqrt{3})^2$. Moreover, with the last three terms, by completing the square, we can see that those last three terms are actually $(y_1/\sqrt{3}+z_1/\sqrt{3})^2$:
$$
x_1^2+x_2^2=\frac{2}{3}+\left(\frac{x_1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2-\left(\frac{y_1}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{z_1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2
$$
Finally, I'll leave it as an exercise to you to show that $(x_1/\sqrt{3})^2-(y_1/\sqrt{3}+z_1/\sqrt{3})^2=0$. Hint: Use the fact that $x_1+y_1+z_1=0$.

Using this final hint, we find that:
$$
x_1^2+x_2^2=\frac{2}{3}
$$
so the final answer is $2/3$.

Comment: Excellent!!! You somewhere wrote "We know that ${x_1}^2+{y_1}^2+{z_1}^2=0"$...it should be $1$ ig

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad Thanks for the catch!

Comment: $\frac{a^2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$ and $\frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ does resemble the 3D Pythagorean theorem. Did you, perchance, find the *magnitude* of these vectors?

Comment: @AgentSmith I don't need to find the magnitudes of the vectors to solve this problem. I just assume without loss of generality that the vectors are unit vectors, i.e. the magnitudes are 1.

Comment: @NobleMushtak, *asante sana*.

Answer (score 1):

First note there is an implicit assumption that neither $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ nor $\langle x,y,z \rangle$ is the zero vector for the problem to make sense.

Next, since $a + b + c = 0$ we have $c = - a - b$, so the vector $\langle a,b,c \rangle$ can be rewritten as  $\langle a,b, - a - b\rangle$.

The assumptions imply that $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ is perpendicular to both $\langle a,b,c\rangle$ and $\langle 1,1,1\rangle$. So it has to be a multiple of the cross product $\langle a,b,c\rangle \times \langle 1,1,1\rangle$  $= \langle c - b, a - c, b - a\rangle$ $= \langle -a-2b, 2a + b, b - a\rangle$. Since the expression you are looking at is invariant under multiplication of $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ by a nonzero scalar, without loss of generality we can assume $\langle x,y,z\rangle = \langle -a-2b, 2a + b, b - a\rangle$.

So we have
$$\langle a,b,c \rangle = \langle a,b, - a - b\rangle$$
$$\langle x,y,z\rangle = \langle -a-2b, 2a + b, b - a\rangle$$
At this point we can just insert these vectors into  ${\displaystyle \frac{a^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2}+\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$ and obtain
$$\frac{a^2}{2a^2 + 2ab + 2b^2 } + \frac{a^2 + 4ab + 4b^2}{6a^2 + 6ab + 6b^2}$$
$$= \frac{4a^2 + 4ab + 4b^2}{6a^2 + 6ab + 6b^2 }$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}$$